# Gradle multi projects and tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle

I use Gradle to configure my new projects and import them into eclipse.
The project `A` (wtp) depends on project `B` (pure java).

- Root

  - A (web application)
  - B (java dependencies)

I try to use gradle's multi project settings. In Project `A` build.gradle I've added
`compile(project(":B"))`.

Inside eclipse I'm able to use the project `B` class, but I'm not able to run it in tomcat because of the following error:

```
"Could not publish to the server. Path for project must have only one segment."
```

Do You have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a compile dependency to B defined in A?

Comment: Yes, I have a dependencies

Comment: Do you apply the ```eclipse-wtp``` plugin to both projects within your ```build.gradle``` file?